# Touch screen events stop working after enabling AccessibilityService on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-service, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to create an AccessibilityService to listen globally for gestures with Xamarin Android.

The service works and receives the gestures and events, but the device stops interpretating these events, it seems that any touch event is discarded. I have tried all combinations I can think about but none works, I must be missing something but dunno what...

Here is the code for the service:

```
[Service(Enabled = true, Exported = false, Permission = "android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"), 
    IntentFilter(new [] { "android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" }),
    MetaData("android.accessibilityservice", Resource = "@xml/serviceconfig")]
public class ActionAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService
{
    public override void OnAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event: " + e.EventType);
    }

    public override void OnInterrupt()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnServiceConnected()
    {
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.EventTypes = EventTypes.GestureDetectionStart | EventTypes.GestureDetectionEnd;
        info.Flags = AccessibilityServiceFlags.RequestFilterKeyEvents | AccessibilityServiceFlags.RequestTouchExplorationMode;
        info.FeedbackType = Android.AccessibilityServices.FeedbackFlags.Generic;
        this.SetServiceInfo(info);
    }

    protected override bool OnKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the content of the servceconfig.xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
       android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"` you are requesting the device to go to Touch Exploration Mode when your service is active.

See [Android Developers Guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfo.html#attr_android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode) and [Touch Exploration Mode](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6006598?hl=en)